# Can't connect my Reactjs programm with database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, odbc

## Running my Reacts program gives me this error:Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/hfsql/dist/index.js 6:11-26
Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'odbc.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\hfsql\node_modules\Odbc\lib\odbc'.

[image]

## Code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can't connect my Reactjs programm with database

Yes and you should not. If you want to use your React app with a database, you should setup a back-end app using some back-end technology like NodeJS, PHP, whatever. It will be your backend app that will interact with your database, and if you want to access data stored in your database from your React Front-end you will make API calls to that back-end. The Backend will be sort of a middleman between your React app and your database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed I had the presumption to be able to attack my HFSQL database directly from my front-end. I'm going to try your method and hope to succeed.